# Upgrade ruby's OpenSSL version?

Tags: ruby, windows, openssl

I am trying to build Ruby from source for Windows, and there doesn't seem to be very good documentation on how I can get a local build of OpenSSL to hook up to my ruby build. Is there some way I should be copying in DLLs/EXEs/whatever in order to build a version of Ruby with the latest OpenSSL version (like 1.0.1r or something)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So yeah, this is both a simple and hard question.

First off, I'm assuming you're using the [RubyInstaller project](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller) and not compiling with MSVC. If you are using MSVC then some of this may be useful, but overall not.

Just for reference this is the code that [actually configures which version to use](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/blob/master/config/dependencies.rb#L18-29).

The next piece of valuable information, the environment RubyInstaller uses to build Ruby is based off of [rubenvb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256138/rubenvb)'s [mingw64 builds](https://github.com/rubenvb/MinGW-w64-build-scripts)([Version 4.7.2 in this case](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/blob/master/config/compilers/mingw64.rb)) and cherry picked MSYS tools. The compiler is important because issues have been known to happen using libraries that aren't built by the same compiler. *I don't actually know much about that area.*

RubyInstaller tries to avoid this problem by providing binaries built with the DevKit with the [OpenKnapsack Project](https://bintray.com/oneclick/OpenKnapsack). The openssl libraries are downloaded from there for RubyInstaller builds. If there is a binary you want then you can upload a working recipe to [the `knapsack-recipes` repo](https://github.com/oneclick/knapsack-recipes) and it will be built in 32 and 64-bit flavors and uploaded. *I do this manually. -sad face-*

So, the **simple** part is you can take any of those binaries you want and just drop the DLL into the Ruby `bin` folder and it will link and use that DLL. But the version that Ruby is compiled with is a hard-coded constant and won't change even though you have a new version of the DLL.

The **hard** part is that if there isn't a recipe for the version you want in the [`knapsack-recipes` repo](https://github.com/oneclick/knapsack-recipes) you have to make one and submit a pull request or find/build the version yourself. And then if you really want to have the correct version hard coded in Ruby you have to change the [config in the rubyinstaller project](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/blob/master/config/dependencies.rb#L18-29) and then build Ruby yourself using a command like:

```
> rake ruby21 DKVER=mingw64-32-4.7.2 #32-bit
> rake ruby21 DKVER=mingw64-64-4.7.2 #64-bit
```

Comment: Sounds good. out of curiosity, how would I change the OpenStruct entries? It looks like they're being used to do some sort of curl to grab files from the internet. Is there a different key I would use for locally built versions of OpenSSL?

so just to make sure, that dkver stuff is only needed for ruby21, right? If I make the changes for ruby19, I can still run my ruby build with the following command, right?
`rake ruby 19`